# Trying to adjust page width via CSS & HTML but it will not let me - Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I have tried everything. Adding via CSS in editor, page template, customizer. I just want to globally apply a certain % page width.

Twenty Twenty Two theme, which is the default theme, so I am confused.

I have tried to put this in the page & theme CSS:

```
.entry-content > *:not(.alignwide):not(.alignfull):not(.alignleft):not(.alignright):not(.is-style-wide) {
max-width: 87rem;
width: calc(100% - 8rem);
```

}

I have tried doing it natively, by switching off the inherit default dimensions and entering in a % and pixel, neither work.

Super confused.

Answer (score 0):

the code is working perfectly with the theme double check your wp-cache.

https://www.loom.com/share/a47139a4f64b48a6b2ba1eb654da96ec

Comment: Welcome mate :)